# How to add content to a main page

Tags: 7, nodes

First Drupal site. I have a custom content type of 'books' which I want to add to the 'books' basic page. I literally have no clue how to do this, or what is the best 'Drupal' way of doing this.

Comment: Did you mean you want a list of books (nodes from your content type 'books') which are attached to the 'books' basic page?

Comment: Yes exactly. I actually got it to work the way I wanted to by creating a custom view showing all the content =books and placed that block into the 'Books' page.

Comment: Yes, the way you have is right. Need views, panels and ctools.

Answer (score 0):

The default Drupal setup is to display a list of all nodes that have their "promoted to front page" box checked.

If you want to display a single node rather than that list, you can create that page and then change the default front page in admin/configuration/site-information by pasting in that page's path to the front page field.

If you would like to display a list that is different from the default list, (like, you want to add filters or display fields or something) then you can install and use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to override the default or to create a new page and set it as the main page in site-information settings as described.